# Is it possible to run PPAPI Flash in the renderer process with Chrome 18 or higher?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

Chrome used to have a "Run PPAPI Flash In The Renderer Process” setting in about:flags, but this is now gone.

To try to mimic that functionality via the commandline I have set the flags: --process-per-tab --ppapi-flash-in-process.

If I run Chrome 20 Canary, and run about:plugins, I see that it is running PPAPI (out-of-process) Flash as well as NPAPI Flash.  I am concerned that it specifically says PPAPI (out-of-process); do I need a separate version of Flash to run it in-process?  If so, is this available and for which platforms?

I am hoping that if I look at the Windows volume mixer and play two Flash sites (such as youtubedoubler.com and a random video at youtube.com) that it would show two entries, but instead I see that if I switch which tab has focus, it changes the volume mixer entry to reflect which one is being seen.  This indicates to me that both tabs are using the same instance of Flash.